# Create API object from a list of YAML object

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I have a list of kubernetes objects defined like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
kind: List
- .....
```

I'd like to parse it with something like `client-go` and gather some information on it.

So I searched and found some piece of code like this:

```
decode := api.Codecs.UniversalDeserializer().Decode
obj, _, err := decode([]byte(f), nil, nil)

lst, err := meta.ExtractList(obj)
for _, o := range lst {
    doSomeThing(o)
}
```

So `obj` and each of its element is `runtime.Object` kind. But I can't seem to find a way to convert that into a concrete kubernetes object like `v1.Pod`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To convert runtime objects to Kubernetes objects, you can do something like:

```
switch typed := obj.(type) {
  case *apiv1.Pod:
    log.Info(typed.Name) // type is Pod
  case *apiv1.Namespace:
  // typed is Namespace
}
```